# How can I set react Hooks to another value when it is already set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first time using React hooks and I have stumbled across a problem I can't solve. I am using the `formAmount` hook to get the input value of store it in `state.amount`. When that happens the amount is supposed to reduce totaling to a number whenever a user puts it in. The problem is that I can't make a new array in the `onChange` event because it catalogs every stroke of the key and it doesn't give me the complete number and I can't set it directly on the `state.amount`. How can I get that amount and store in an array?

Here is my code:

```
const Transactions = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([
        {
            expense: [],
            amount: [],
            id: ''
        }

    ])

    const [formExpense, setFormExpense] = useState('')
    const [formAmount, setFormAmount] = useState([])



    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        addExpense()
        e.target.reset()
    }
    // add total of array of amount
    let sum = formAmount.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        { return accumulator += currentValue }
    }, 0)

    // push value of input to array
    const addExpense = (e) => {

        setState([...state, { expense: formExpense, amount: [...formAmount], id: Math.random() * 100 }])

    }


    return (
        <div className="transactions">

            <div className="expenses">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="expense"
                        className="formfield"
                        name="expense"
                        placeholder="Expense..."
                        onChange={(e) => setFormExpense(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="amount"
                        className="formfield"
                        name="amount"
                        placeholder="Amount..."
                        onChange={(e) => setFormAmount([Number(e.target.value)])}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="finalbalance ">

                <div className="finalexpense final">
                    Total Expense
                    {'$' + sum.toLocaleString()}
                    {
                        state.map(stat => {
                            return (

                                <div key={stat.id}>

                                    <h3 className="outputexpense output">{stat.expense + stat.amount}</h3>
                                </div>


                            )
                        })
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    )
}
```

Comment: So you want to perform reduction after the user has entered the complete number on the input?

Comment: Yes, but I need an array for it to function so it can add the incoming numbers. However on the click it keeps re-rendering the amount because the number are not stored in an array.

Comment: Since you're dealing with amounts. Don't trigger state update `onChange`, rather get the user to press a button when they have entered the value and then perform state update.

Comment: If you use onChance, every key stroke will force update...

Comment: let me suggest a proper way of going about it. Give me a minute.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of that. I was so focused on that particular solution I didn't venture out of that thinking. Thank you. But I know it's kind of hard to access the event method while using hooks in a function. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, tell me why is `formAmount` expecting a []? because both expense and amount are set at the same time. you're not setting multiple `formAmount`s one each form submission

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to be a list, because you're setting one value on every form submission instance

Comment: formAmount is expecting an array because I am trying to add the total of the user input by using reduce.

Comment: Your data is really structured incorrectly, look at state.. it contains a list of object with properties `expense` and `amount` and both those properties hold lists... now if you configure `formAmount` to hold a list that means you only allow a user to enter an amount with only 1 digit right? because each key stroke represent 1 digit and then the state updates...

Comment: The state does fire every time there is a key event but it only renders on the click. I am new to react, how would you form the structure?

Comment: It depends on the scenario, so basically what you're trying to do is add different expenses right? and then get the total sum of those expenses, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build a budget calc that logs the expense and the amount and returns the total amount of those expense. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Your `state` structure is incorrect. I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay. I have converted the code into javascript... Run the code snippet and check that it works on my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's is the answer for you. I have done a Fiddle as well [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mosiaonline/wgy06rd7/3/)

```js
function Transaction(props){

    const [listOfExpenses, setlistOfExpenses] = React.useState([]);
    const [expense, setExpense] = React.useState("");
    const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(0);
    const [totalExpenditure, setTotalExpenditure] = React.useState(0);


    const handleInputChange = (hookSetterMethod) => (e) =>{
        let {value} = e.target;
        return hookSetterMethod(value);
    }

    const addExpense = (expenseObject) => {
        setlistOfExpenses([...listOfExpenses, expenseObject])
    }

    const getTotalExpenditure = (listOfExpenses) =>
    {
            if(listOfExpenses.length > 0)
        {
          let tempExpenseAmountList = listOfExpenses.map((expense, id)=>{
              if(expense.amount)
              {
                  return expense.amount;
              }else{
                  return 0;
              }
          });

          return tempExpenseAmountList.reduce((accumulator, currentVal)=>{
              return Number(accumulator) + Number(currentVal);
          })
        }
        return 0;
    }

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        setTotalExpenditure(getTotalExpenditure(listOfExpenses));
    }, [listOfExpenses])

    const handleFormSubmission = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        addExpense({
            amount,
            expense
        });
    }
    
    const renderExpenses = (expenseList) => {
      return expenseList.map((expense, id)=>{
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{++id}</td>
            <td>{expense.expense}</td>
            <td>: ${expense.amount}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      });
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Add your expenses below</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmission}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Expense</label>
                        <input value={expense} onChange={handleInputChange(setExpense)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Amount</label>
                        <input value={amount} onChange={handleInputChange(setAmount)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                      <td>Id</td>
                      <td>Expense</td>
                      <td>Amount</td>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                {renderExpenses(listOfExpenses)}
                <tr className="total">
                  <td>Total Expenses</td>
                  <td>: ${totalExpenditure}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Transaction />, 
document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
table{
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.total{
  display: table;
  border-top: 1px solid #434649;
  border-bottom: 2px double #434649;
  color: #f80000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Okay. I have converted the code into javascript... Run the code snippet  and check that it works.

Comment: It works perfectly, but I want to be able to do it by myself. If I could ask, how long have you been coding?

Comment: I've been coding with react for about 7 months now.. I'm a professional Angular developer. But I've since migrated to React and it's just as simple and easy to get around with. But my coding experience span over 7 years from Java EE (where I started years ago) to ASP.NET Core (What I use now)...

Comment: Also, where did those parameters come from like hooksettermethod and expenseObject. How did you know where to place them and when to place them.

Comment: I made `handleInputChange ` to be generic, meaning it works for all inputs because it uses the corresponding `hookSetterMethod` that is passed to it to update state. It's just another way of doing things. If I didn't do this, I would have to create a handler method for every input... which is not a very good option ... remember you want your code to be short as possible.

Comment: With `addExpense ` method, it receives an object as a parameter. That object is made up of the `expense` and `amount`... It doesn't actually have to be that way... because you can still use it without passing anything. By just accessing state properties directly inside that method. I just choose to always pass parameters as input to functions... even if they don't return any value. This has come with my experience from other languages..

Comment: React is very easy... It's gets tough depending on what you want to do with it... Otherwise, learning the APIs is straight forward... Angular is the same... it depends on what you're building, that's what determines the difficulty of of the platform

Comment: Thanks for responding! I hope I get as good as you one day.

Comment: You will for sure. Code everyday, read API's and you'll go far. Don't forget to mark this as answer as well. Thank you Alanaj.

Comment: Sorry, last question? What are API's? Is it documentation?

Comment: Yes, during spare time... dive deeper into react's source files and see what's available... for example  from `react` package... locate that package in node_modules and check the index file... see what method and other great stuff are included in that library. That's one of the best way to get to know react better.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I will definitely look into that.

Comment: I was studying your code and realized you can turn the const variable into objects. I did not know you could do that.

Comment: any variable market with `const` cannot be reassigned.

Comment: I know, I just saw that you used expense and amount const and used those in addExpense, You created an object out of those variables and then injected it into the list const.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yes, I created an object which I passed to `addExpense` that's correct.